# Combining and Reshaping rows and columns of 2 dataframes in R or Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, reshape

There are two tables - Table A and Table B:

Table A: Product Attributes This table contains two columns; the first one is a unique product ID represented by an integer, the second is a string containing a collection of attributes assigned to that product.

```
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|      product        |       tags            |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          100        | chocolate, sprinkles  |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          101        | chocolate, filled     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
|          102        | glazed                |
|---------------------|-----------------------|
```

Table B: Customer Attributes The second table contains two columns as well; the first one is a string that contains a customer name, the second is an integer that contains a product number. The product IDs from column two are the same as the product IDs from column one of Table A.

```
customer    product
A           100
A           101
B           101
C           100
C           102
B           101
A           100
C           102
```

You are asked to create a table matching this format, where the contents of the cells represent the count of occurrences of product attribute by customer.

```
customer    chocolate   sprinkles   filled  glazed
A               ?           ?         ?        ?
B               ?           ?         ?        ?
C               ?           ?         ?        ?
```

Can anybody help me solve this in R or Python?

Comment: Can you please add some sample data to your post?

Comment: Can you please add your attempted code in R or Python with any issues to your post?

Answer (score 1):

We join by the 'product' column, split the 'tags' at the delimiter to expand the rows, get the frequency of 'tags', 'customer' with `count` and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   right_join(df2) %>% 
   separate_rows(tags) %>%
   count(tags, customer) %>% 
   spread(tags, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  customer chocolate filled glazed sprinkles
#  <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A                3      1      0         2
#2 B                2      2      0         0
#3 C                1      0      2         1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(product = 100:102, tags = c("chocolate, sprinkles", 
"chocolate, filled", "glazed")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(customer = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", 
 "C"), product = c(100L, 101L, 101L, 100L, 102L, 101L, 100L, 102L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The python method can be simplified substantially, using  built in methods to get the dummy variables. Then `merge` followed by `groupby`+`sum`. Starting with data provided by @SuryaMurali

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.concat([df_A, df_A.tags.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')], 1).drop(columns='tags')
df_B.merge(df_A).drop(columns='product').groupby('customer').sum()
```

#### Output:

```
           filled   sprinkles  chocolate  glazed
customer                                        
A               1           2          3       0
B               2           0          2       0
C               0           1          1       2
```